# Rails4で画像ファイルをupload処理をした際、ファイルネームが文字化けする

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, 文字化け

まずはじめに、私はプログラム初心者です。

環境：rails 4.1.6, ruby 2.1.3

kconvを利用してコード変換処理をしていましたが、MacOS上にvagrantを入れているローカル環境では上手く保存されず、文字化けしております。また、UTF-8環境であるため、kconvを利用せずやっても上手く行きませんでした。

vagrantは標準のUbuntuを使っています。

どう処理すれば、日本語ファイルネームを文字化けせずに保存できるのでしょうか？
ちなみに、viewには日本語で正しく表示されるため、経由した後に文字化けしていると思われます。
お手数おかけしますが、ご教示のほどお願い致します。

データの流れですが、

MacBookAir(MacOS X 10.10 Yosemite) → vagrant(Ubuntu10.3+Rails4.1.6+ruby2.1.3)　→ Macのvagrantフォルダ

となります。

1. 今回のアップロード対象ファイル名：福ノ神仙壷四郎.jpg
2. 実行された後のファイル名：τªÅπâÄτÑ₧_Σ╗Öσú╖σ¢¢ΘâÄ.jpg
3. 期待する格納されるべきファイル名：福ノ神仙壷四郎.jpg
4. ファイルの確認方法：Macターミナル及びファインダーからの目視確認

[Ruby2.1からencoding機能が実装されている](http://techracho.bpsinc.jp/baba/2013_12_26/15026)ようなので、ここらへんも考慮してみたいと思います。

```
require 'kconv'
# ＜中略＞
def upload_process
  #アップロードファイルを取得
  file = params[:upfile]
  #ファイルのベース名（パスを除いた部分）を取得
  name = file.original_filename
  #許可する拡張子を定義
  perms = ['.jpg', '.jpeg', '.gif', '.png']
  if !perms.include?(File.extname(name).downcase)
    result = 'アップロードできるのは画像ファイルのみです。'
  #アップロードファイルのサイズが1MB以下であるか
  elsif file.size > 1.megabyte
    result = 'ファイルサイズは1MBまでです。'
  else
    #ファイル名をUTF-8→Shift-JISにエンコード
    name = name.kconv(Kconv::SJIS, Kconv::UTF8)
    #/public/docフォルダ配下にアップロードファイルを保存
    File.open("public/docs/#{name}", 'wb') { |f| f.write(file.read) }
    result = "#{name.toutf8}をアップロードしました。"
  end
  #成功／エラーメッセージを保存
  render text: result
end
```

Comment: 「name = name.kconv(Kconv::UTF8, Kconv::UTF8)」変換元と変換先の文字コードが両方とも UTF8 となっていますが、よろしいのでしょうか？

Comment: 文字化けのタグを追加しました。

Comment: @heliac2001 さん　ご変身ありがとうございます。「'name = name.kconv(Kconv::UTF8, Kconv::UTF8)'」は「'name = name.kconv(Kconv::SJIS, Kconv::UTF8)'」の誤りです。ただ、これをコメントアウトしてもやはり文字化けしてMac内部のディレクトリに格納されました。

Comment: @tomute さん　タグ付けありがとうございます。

Comment: @Junichi Itoさん　コード修正ありがとうございました。

Comment: 「文字化け」だけだとよくわからないので
1. 期待しているファイル名
2. 実際のファイル名
3. ファイル名をどうやって確認しているのか
以上3つがあると解答しやすいと思います。

Comment: @Seiei Higaさん ご指摘部分を本文に反映させました。

Comment: Vagrant 内の Ubuntu では LANG や LC_ALL といった環境変数の設定はどうなっていますか？ 例えば 「echo $LANG」や「echo $LC_ALL」の結果を教えていただけますか。

Comment: @heliac2001さん echo $LANG、echo $LC_ALLをターミナルから打った処、en_US.UTF-8と表示されました。

Comment: LANG と LC_ALL を ja_JP.UTF-8 に設定してみてもらえませんか？ 方法はルート権限で「update-locale LANG=ja_JP.UTF-8 LC_ALL=ja_JP.UTF-8」を実行します。そして Ubuntu を再起動してもう一度 echo 〜 を実行して ja_JP.UTF-8 に切り替わっているかどうか確認してみてください。

Comment: update-localeコマンドだけではダメでしたので、OSのパッケージを追加してupdateしました。echo $LANGコマンドで確認したところ無事変更されていました。その状態で同じようにファイルのuploadを行いましたが同様にτªÅπâÄτÑ₧_Σ╗Öσú╖σ¢¢ΘâÄ.jpgで保管されました。

Comment: 「name = name.kconv(Kconv::SJIS, Kconv::UTF8)」の部分はまだそのままですか？

Comment: この部分はコメントアウトしています。また、kconvの読み込みもやめています。

Comment: ごめんなさい、LANG や LC_ALL の設定は無関係でしたね。。。

Comment: Kawaiさん、たびたびすみません、「name = name.kconv(Kconv::SJIS, Kconv::UTF8)」の部分を「name.encode!('CP437', 'UTF-8-MAC')」「name.force_encoding('UTF-8')」の2行に変えて試してみていただけますか？

Comment: @heliac2001さん'Encoding::UndefinedConversionError at /ctrl/upload_process
U+798F to IBM437 in conversion from UTF8-MAC to UTF-8 to IBM437'と表示されました。

Comment: すみません、順番が逆なのとエンコーディングの指定を間違えていました。最初に「name.force_encoding('CP437')」を、次に「name.encode!('CP437', 'UTF-8-MAC')」としていただけますか。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: encode!が使えませんでした。エラーはNoMethodError at /ctrl/upload_process
undefined method `enc‌​ode!' for #<String:0x0000000574fae0>

と表示されました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

一般論として、アップロードされたファイル名をそのままディスク上のファイル名として保存するのは避けるべきです。特にマルチバイト文字の扱いに知識が無いならなおさらです。また、Railsは何もしなければ普通UTF-8文字列になってるはずなので、kconvとかString#encodeとかはとりあえず忘れてください。

代案として、ファイル名をエンコードして保存する方法と、DBにファイル名を保持しておく方法を紹介します。

### エンコードする方法

```
def encode_filename(filename)
  filename.unpack("H*")[0]
end

def upload_process
  file = params[:upfile]
  name = file.original_filename
  File.open("public/docs/#{encode_filename(name)}", 'wb') { |f| f.write(file.read) }
  result = "#{name}をアップロードしました。"
  render text: result
end
```

"あいうえお.txt"がe38182e38184e38186e38188e3818a2e747874で保存されます。

読み込むときも同様に

```
filename = "あいうえお.txt"
open(encode_filename(filename)).read
```

保存されているファイル名から元のファイルを取り出すには

```
def decode_filename(filename)
  s = [filename].pack("H*")
  s.force_encoding('utf-8')
  s
end

decode_filename("e38182e38184e38186e38188e3818a2e747874") # => "あいうえお.txt"
```

### DBにファイル名を保存しておく方法

モデルの作成
`$ rails g model attachment filename`

```
class Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base
  SAVE_PATH = "public/docs/"
  attr_reader :file

  after_create :save_file

  def file=(file)
    @file = file
    self.filename = file.original_filename
  end

  def save_file
    open(SAVE_PATH + self.id.to_s, "wb") {|f| f.write(file.tempfile.read) }
  end

  def load_file
    open(SAVE_PATH + self.id.to_s).read
  end
end
```

controllerでは

```
 Attachment.create(file: params[:up_file]) 
 #ファイルの保存。public/docs/1に保存されます。モデルのidなので連番で増えていきます

 attachment = Attachment.find(1)
 attachment.filename #=> "あいうえお.txt"
 attachment.load_file #=> "ファイルの中身"
```

のように使えます。

実際にはファイルだけを扱うのではなく他の情報と一緒に扱うのでしょうからそちらのモデルに関連を持たせればいいでしょう

Answer (score 5):

Mac OSX ではパス名のエンコーディングに `UTF-8-MAC` という NFD(Normalization Form D)形式の UTF-8 を使っているとのことです。ですので、以下の様にして変換する必要がありそうです。

```
require 'iconv'

name = Iconv.iconv("UTF-8-MAC", "UTF-8", name)
```

OSX システムが手元になく、実際に確認はしていませんので、間違っていましたらごめんなさい。

追記:

ruby 1.9 以降であれば `encode()` で `UTF-8-MAC` を使うことができますので、

```
name.encode!('UTF-8-MAC', 'UTF-8')
```

と書けます。ただ、これは今回の問題との関連性は薄いと思われますので参考程度に留めておいて下さい(後々必要になる場合もあるかもしれません)。

ところで、以下の ruby コードを実行しますと、

```
s = '福ノ神_仙壷四郎.jpg'
s.encode!('UTF-8-MAC', 'CP437')
s.force_encoding('UTF-8')
File.open(s, "wb").close()
```

カレントディレクトリに以下の様なファイルができます。

```
τªÅπâÄτÑ₧_Σ╗Öσú╖σ¢¢ΘâÄ.jpg
```

UTF-8 エンコーディングである文字列 `福ノ神仙壷四郎.jpg` を `CP437` エンコーディングだとして UTF-8 へ変換してしまっていることになります。もしかしてファイルをアップロードする際の `charset` の設定(HTMLヘッダ内の `Content-Type`)がおかしくなっているのかもしれません。

Comment: @heliac2001さんありがとうございます。試してみましたが、iconvはmacのモジュールなので、vagrantで動いているubunts上のruby+railsでは呼び出せませんでした。ただ、現在のruby+railsであればencoding機能の中にuft-8-macの処理が出来るようにはなっているようなので、構文だけ間違えなければ大丈夫かなと思います。

Answer (score 4):

原因がよくわからないので僕がデバッグするならどうするか考えてみます。

まずRailsを使わず、ターミナルのコマンドなどを使って期待しているファイル名が保存できるか確認します。

```
echo 日本語 > public/docs/日本語コマンド.txt
```

つぎに、paramsの内容を使わず、期待した日本語ファイル名でファイルが保存できるか確認します。

```
def upload_process
  name = "日本語nameを自分で書く.txt"
  File.open("public/docs/#{name}", 'wb') {|f| f.write('日本語') }
  render text: "{name}をアップロードしました。"
end
```

次に`kconv`を使わずにparamsの内容を使ってファイルが保存できるか確認します。
この際、実際に`File.open`に渡しているファイル名を確認できるようにします。

```
def upload_process
  file = params[:upfile]
  name = file.original_filename
  path = "public/docs/#{name}"

  File.open(path, 'wb') {|f| f.write('パラメータをそのまま使っています') }
  render text: "{path}に#{name}をアップロードしました。"
end
```

paramsから受け取ったファイル名をそのまま使っても、期待した日本語ファイル名がテキストとして表示されていない場合、文字のエンコーディングの取り扱い方が間違っていそうなので、`kconv`などを使って、期待しているファイル名になるよう、文字コードを変換します。

```
require 'kconv'

def upload_process
  file = params[:upfile]
  name = file.original_filename
  path = "public/docs/#{name.toutf8}" # toutf8する
  File.open(path, 'wb') {|f| f.write('パラメータをそのまま使っています') }
  render text: "{path}に#{name}をアップロードしました。"
end
```

これらの確認の最中で、期待した日本語ファイル名がテキストとして表示されているのに実際のファイル名が文字化けしている場合は、ファイル名の確認方法が間違っていないかどうかなど、Railsとは関係ない部分で間違っていないかどうかを疑います。

また、`upload_process`の内容を変更して確認する前に、都度`public/docs`ディレクトリの内容を削除しておくとよいでしょう。
なぜなら、`upload_process`にバグがあり、ファイルが保存されない場合に、前回のファイルが残っていると「ちゃんと保存されてるけど前と結果がかわらないなぁ」と勘違いをし、バグがあって保存されていないことに気がつかないかもしれないからです。

参考まで。

Comment: Higaさん ご丁寧にありがとうございます。参考に参考にさせて頂きます。

Answer (score 1):

こちらを参照にしてみたらいかがでしょうか.

/config/initializers/carrierwave.rb

```
CarrierWave::SanitizedFile.sanitize_regexp = /[^[:word:]\.\-\+]/
```

[日本語のファイル名が____に置き換わってしまうのを防ぐ](http://f96q.github.io/blog/2012/08/02/carrierwave/)

Comment: @seventhesenseさんありがとうございます。ただ、ド素人なので、これだけ渡されてもどのように実装すればよいのかが検討ついてないです。この先のgithubのsourceを移植する感じでしょうか？それともこのモジュールを入れて、指定先の構文を書くということでしょうか？

そんなこともわからないレベルなので、申し訳ないです。

Comment: 言葉が足りず失礼しました.
/config/initializers/carrierwave.rb というファイルを作成して、上のコードを1行だけ書き込んで、サーバーを再起動して、再度、ファイル名が文字化けするか実験してみてもらえますか.

Comment: @seventhsenseさん　ご丁寧なご回答ありがとうございました。試してみます。試した後またご報告いたします。

Comment: 試しましたが、サーバ起動時にerrorが吐出されます。2012年のものなので、rails4では動かないのではないでしょうか？

Comment: rails4の環境で試してみましたが、rails4.1.7で問題なく動作しました（サーバーが起動しないということはありませんでした.）.詳しくは、 https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#filenames-and-unicode-chars を参照してください.
あとは、一般的なことですが、単に「文字化け」ではなく、どのような文字がどのように化けるか、「サーバーがエラーを吐く」でなく、どのようなエラーメッセージが表示されるかと記載された方が、より回答が期待できると思います.あまりお力になれないようですみません.

Comment: @seventhesenseさん ファイル名について本文に追記いたしました。このモジュールが使えるということがわかりましたので、githubを参考に動かしてみたいと思います。